# $p$-adic norm bound for Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Bernoulli polynomials are as usual generated by:

$$
  \frac{te^{xt}}{e^t -1} = \sum_{j \geq 0}B_k(x) \frac{t^j}{j!}
$$
they are just polynomials, for $x\in \mathbf{Z}_p$(the ring of $p$-adic integers) is possible to give a bound of the $p$-adic norm of $B_k(x)$? Any references?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: The trivial bound is that for $k$ large enough ($v_p(xp^k)> p/(p-1)$) then $e^{x p^k t}, \frac{e^{tp^k}-1}{tp^k}$ are in $\Bbb{Z}_p[[t]]^\times=\Bbb{Z}_p^\times+t\Bbb{Z}_p[[t]]$. This hold for $x$ algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ thus this gives a bound for the coefficients of $B_k(X)$ too.

Comment: You should explain how is defined this p-adic norm, using the p-adic norm of its coefficients, I imagine...

Comment: For the true valuations look at 'Washington cyclotomic fields pdf' chapter 5.2